# Search Criteria as a range

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, spreadsheet, textjoin

I am trying to find a way to use a range as a search criteria.

The problem is as follows:

Below is a range of names in `NAMES!A2:A`.

```
Names 
Benjamin Douglas
Caitlin Enriquez
Cristina Butler
Emily Furse
Jenny Ford
Liana Fowler
Lowri Donald
Rachel McBride
Rochelle Guy
Samina Swanson
Sol Wills
Sonya Cantu
```

On another sheet, I allow input of multiple names in another sheet in the range `SEARCH!B:B`. Upon entering a range of names, I would like it to return one string that contains any string within `SEARCH!B2:B` into `SEARCH!A2`

```
Searching Criteria
Jennifer
Jennie
Jenny
Jenni
Jenn
Jen
```

And following the search criteria the formula would return in `SEARCH!A2` the string `Jenny Ford`

I have tried multiple formulas including `INDEX` and `FILTER` but none of them accept a range as a search criteria.

I have included an example sheet if needed: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fztl6OgtclV4gXxBWqTyTvRAt8EAp81xCYoHbDT3AcE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share your progress

Comment: @Osm i have tried ```=VLOOKUP(B2:B,NAMES!A1:A,1,1)``` as well alongside ```=FILTER(NAMES!A1:A,NAMES!A1:A=B1:B)``` I cannot find my formula on index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
=INDEX( NAMES!A2:A,MATCH(TRUE, REGEXMATCH(NAMES!A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|",1,C2:C)),0),1)
```

[image]

Help links

[**`INDEX`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) - [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) - [**`REGEXMATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will put this in :)\

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(NAMES!A2:A, REGEXMATCH(NAMES!A2:A, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)))
```

[image]

Comment: `(?i)` to get the match reardless if upper or lower case